# Try out a list of arguments with function - python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a list of arguments which I am trying to pass to a function and then loop through it and create variables with the data (if it is possible, some arguments create a TypeError in combination with other arguments passed to the function). But when I put it in for loop then I get nothing but Typerrors even though I know that some combinations will give a valid answer.

```
arg1 = 1
arg2 = 2
arguments = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for x in arguments 
   try:
      text[x]=function(x, arg1, arg2)
      print(text[x])
   except TypeError:
      continue
```

How should I try different options with a function?

edit: changed typo in TypeError

Comment: Can you show us the full error traceback?  Perhaps the TypeError is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe it is a type in your code but you have to write `except TypeError:` because the spelling of [type error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) is in this snippet false.

Comment: This code does not even compile. Please provide a working script. Most likely we will not be able to help you without you providing the code of `function`  and `text` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown (after you correct missing colon and misspelling of TypeError) will give a NameError because Text is referenced before it is set.  instead do

```
arg1 = 1
arg2 = 1
arguments = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
text = []
for x in arguments :
    try :
        text.append(func(arg1,arg2,x))
    except NameError:
       continue
```

Comment: Thank you, solution worked. I guess I just didn't know how to append a list and that caused TypeErrors all the time, even if the function gave valid results with the arguments.

Comment: Please help me out and upvote my answer :)

Comment: I did but my upvotes are not shown as my reputation is too low.

Comment: Thank you, pytsep.  Keep coding and have fun :)